# Bizarre behavior with VS 2012, EF 5, and Oracle llg database - telling me to install .NET 4.5 but it's already there

Tags: oracle, frameworks, entity

I am wrestling with one of those wonderful idiosyncrasices that crop up when you don't use 100% microsoft.  Our company uses Oracle 11g, not SQL Server.  After a long battle, I was finally able to connect to the Oracle database and generate the "code first reverse engineer" POCOs and such with the EF Power Tools.  There are hundreds of tables in the database and I saw no way to specify a subset of those, so it took hours to generate the code. Tools/components are VS2012 (C#), Oracle 11g, EF 5, "Power tools" for EF, Windows 7 Enterprise.

I wrote some extremely simple code to see the auto-generated classes work:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Entities;
using Entities.Models;

namespace EntitiesConsoleTests
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Press <Enter> to begin...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                using (var db = new Context())
                {
                    var q = from usr in db.USERS
                            orderby usr.USERNAME
                            select usr;
                    foreach (var u in q)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(u.USERNAME);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);

            }
            Console.Write("Press <Enter>");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

When I run this test program in VS2012, I get no output beyond a quick flash-up of an output window that does not remain anywhere near long enough to read something.  So, I built the program, opened a CMD window, and ran it from the DOS prompt.  This is what I got for output:

(Our firewall seems to be keeping me from posting the image, so I'll approximate it in text.)

I get a dialog entitled "EntitiesConsoleTests.exe - This application could not be started."

```
      ( X ) This application requires one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:

              .NET Framework, Version=v4.5

      Do you want to install this .NET Framework version now?

                                             [ Yes ]   [ No ]
```

The problem is that 4.5 is ALREADY installed, so I am at somewhat of a loss trying to figure out what the REAL problem is.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Now when I just open the project in VS2012, it prompts me to install Framework 4.5 (which is already installed.)

Comment: I was also wondering if I have some strange DLL version issues: The relevant DLLS are:EntityFramework
EntityFramework.dll
Runtime version v4.0.30319
Version 5.0.0.0

System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
Runtime version v4.0.30319
Version 4.0.0.0

System.Data
System.Data.dll
Runtime version v4.0.30319
Version 4.0.0.0

System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
Runtime version v4.0.30319
Version 4.0.0.0

System.Data.Entity
System.Data.Entity.dll
Runtime version v4.0.30319
Version 4.0.0.0

Comment: This morning I downloaded and installed the very latest updates for the .NET platform and VS2012.  No change, even trying to open the solution prompts for installing 4.5.

Comment: This is solved, I had some strange DLL mismatch issues, once I corrected that problem, I no longer got the bogus error message, but had other problems (posting those on a different thread.)